# Why does Rachel hate living at the other apartment?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

Rachel absolutely hates living in Joey and Chandler's apartment after losing the game and bet to them.

***REFRESHER***
The bet was if Monica and Rachel lost the game, then Chandler and Joey move into Monica and Rachel's apartment.

She says she hates the color, hates how it smells like birds, and how its a "guys apartment".

HOWEVER...
When she later moves in with Joey due to Monica and Chandler getting together,  the apartment is in even worse condition than it was when she was previously living there with the well known neat freak Monica.

It just didn't make too much sense to me, and I know that this is just a ***nitpick***, and it could just be an oversight of the writers and crew, due to how many episodes were made.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at the two circumstances that resulted in her move.

**The Bet**

Monica and Rachel lose the apartment after a game with Joey and Chandler. When Joey and Chandler are moving in, Rachel seems to think it's a joke.

Think about it for a second, if someone told you to get up and move into another apartment, especially one that seems smaller than Monica's would you do it?

Her bed room is probably customized the way she likes it, if she were to move, she would have to spend time re-customizing it.

**Chandler Moves In**

Remember again, Rachel didn't think she would have to move out, she thought Chandler would move in, and it would be the three of them.

However, the circumstances are different, after Las Vegas, Monica and Chandler agree to move in together. She attempts to move in with Ross, but they are still married unknowing to Rachel until the lawyer calls, at which point she furious. She eventually moves in with Phoebe, but the apartment burns down. This leaves Joey which means, Naked Thursdays or Wednesdays ;D.

Out of necessity she moves in with Joey. She still lives close to her friends, and she doesn't need to get to know a new roommate.

Comment: Ahh nicely put, great answer!

Comment: I never thought about it that way, just a quick thought. But yeah the circumstances were very different.  It was Rachel's "Transponster" answer that was her undoing lol.

Comment: Let’s not also forget: across from the window in Joey’s room (where Rachel lived the first time) the neighbor liked to sing loudly out the window, which Rachel HATED. When she moves back in to the apartment in later seasons, she takes Chandlers room, which we can assume doesn’t have the same problem :)